# populating a byte array from the network

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, network-programming

I am putting together a fairly simple server that listens for a connection
then creates this thread - textbook java code - then accepts data on that connection.

I am following a protocol that the manufacturer has laid out for SOM and EOM as below. 
I then simply populate a byte array with using a byte counter.

I think this is the simplest doing so. It seems to work fine. Is there any possible problem with taking this approach. I want to be sure using a bytecounter with an array is acceptable. I can't see anyway that bytecounter could get out of sync or anything like that. I like to keeps things simple. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
//THREAD setup above.....

        int i = 0;
        int bytecounter = 0;            
        byte[] inbyte = new byte[1024];            
        byte b ;

while(true) {
    int bytecounter = 0;
try{
    while( ( b = disIn.readByte() ) !=  (byte)0xfe ){               
                if( b == (byte)0xfd  ){                     
                    inbyte = new byte[1024];
                    inbyte[0] = b;
                    bytecounter = 1;                        
                }
                else {                  
                     inbyte[bytecounter] = b;
                     bytecounter++;                     
                }                
            }
        }catch ( java.io.EOFException ioef ){
            System.out.println("EOF received" );
            break;
        }
//do stuff with the inbyte[] data....
// and come back through the while(true) loop
}
```

Comment: Why all the blank lines? Don't you want anyone to see the occasional bit of code?

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling escapes. Any protocol where bytes have special values must have an escape value as well, so that those bytes can be transmitted as data. Probably ESC is used as the escape value, so that ESC SOM means the SOM byte, ESC EOM means the EOM byte, and of course ESC ESC means the ESC byte.